# spring boot static resource 404 error

Tags: spring-boot, static-resource

I am studying spring boot.
And now I have to deploy my static resources to the web project, linking it,
but it returns 404 error

[image]

Also, when I access to "localhost:8080/appie/resources/js/common.js" browser returns 404 error(my context path is /appie).

What could be that reason?

```
server.contextPath=/appie
```

Comment: What is your context path?

Comment: "appie" is my context path

Comment: [**Do not post images of code or errors!**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714)

Comment: my bad, i will edit it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Boot by convention serves static resources under `src/main/resources/static`.
The path of the resource will be relative to this, so if you put `common.js` under `static` resources, you will be able to access to it in:
localhost:8080/appie/common.js

To access to it in as `resources/js/common.js` create this folder structure under `static`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, now i can go on.

Answer (score 0):

You should read [this guide about serving static content with spring boot](https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot).

It says the following:

> Spring Boot will automatically add static web resources located within any of the following directories:

- /META-INF/resources/
- /resources/
- /static/
- /public/

After placing your js file in one of this directories you can access it via $host:$port/$contextPath/common.js